# Show that $\frac{1}{e^{t}-1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-n t} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, power-series

> Show that  $$  \frac{1}{e^{t}-1} =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  e^{-n t} 
>   $$

I am a bit confused because we have a series similar to the geometric series.

What is the proof of this an equity?

Reference:

- http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/213b_spring_05/functional_equation_by_residues.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a geometric series with a ratio of $e^{-t}$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-nt}=\lim_{n \to \infty}e^{-t}\frac{1-e^{-nt}}{1-e^{-t}}=
e^{-t}\frac{1}{1-e^{-t}} = \frac{1}{e^{t}(1-e^{-t})} = \frac{1}{e^{t}-1}$$

Comment: Clear, many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For $t > 0$, $0 < e^{-t} < 1$. Thus,
$$
\frac{1}{e^t - 1} = \frac{e^{-t}}{1 - e^{-t}} = e^{-t}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-nt}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-(n+1)t} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-nt}
$$